# Registry Key is not getting created inside HKCR using powershell script

Tags: powershell

I'm new to this and want to create a registry inside HKCR using powershell, but its not creating when i tries to run complete script at once.
**However it gets created when i select that part and run seperately.**

Am i missing something

Here is my code for creating a registry:

```
        if (Get-PSDrive HKCR -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
        #Write-Host 'The X: drive is already in use.'
        } else {
        New-PSDrive -PSProvider Registry -Root HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT -Name HKCR
        }
        
        $path4="HKCR:\CLSID\"
        New-Item -Path $path4 -Name "<key Name>" -Force
        $path5=$path4+"<key Name>"
        New-ItemProperty $path5 -Name ‘(Default)’ -Value "PanPlapProvider" -Force
```

Any help will be thankfull.

Comment: HKCR is the same than `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes`, have you tried  this path ?

Comment: @CFou not same, but partially. It also includes HKCU:\Software\Classes

Answer (score 1):

`HKCR` hive does not exist actually. This **virtual** registry hive is combined of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes`.

[Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/hkey-classes-root-key) says:

> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT key provides a view of the registry that merges the
> information from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes with the
> information from HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes.
>
> ...
>
> To change the settings for the interactive user, store the changes
> under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes rather than
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.

etc, read this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/hkey-classes-root-key) carefully.